# How do I connect this electric motor

Tags: motor

I got this old electric motor from a friend of mine, and I don't really know the right way to connect it to electricity supply. It's a IMEX (type = YC112M-4) motor.
I've tried to look for the wiring diagram on Google, but I couldn't find any. 
Could someone help me, please?

[image]

Comment: I'd go with connecting power to Z1 and Z2

Comment: @Jasen Thank you for the suggestion. I've done it that way and it worked, but I just wanna confirm wether the connection is right. So as not to cause any damage to the motor on the long run.

Comment: Checking the current vs the nameplate would somewhat confirm that the connection is ok. The current with no load connected shouldn't be more than about 40 percent of rated current. With a question like this, it would be good to post a clear close-up picture of the nameplate and the terminal block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a motor designed to run at 220V / 50Hz, which is the common standard single-phase voltage on 5 continents.  If you want to run it in North America, you'll want to get a VFD.

The spin speed is "nominal" 1450 RPM, which is dead-nuts correct for a 4-pole motor.

You'll need to pay close attention to the "KW" or "KVA" marking in the upper left of the nameplate, which is obscured in your photo.  A standard Euro socket is only good for about 3 KVA; if the motor needs more, you'll need to provision a special circuit just for it.

Comment: @Happer Thanks for your response. Is "KW" the same as "KVA" in this case? On the nameplate, 2.2 KW (3hp) was written.

Comment: @dammy999 close, but not quite. KW is the the part of the AC sinewave  it uses, however KVA is the whole sinewave that distribution equipment must deliver.

Comment: It should be OK to run it on North American 240 VAC 60 Hz. No VFD needed, but might be handy if you want variable speed. However, old motors like this may experience insulation failure due to high frequency PWM. And also it is single phase, with start and/or run capacitors, which are highly frequency dependent.